# How to bind multiple object property to ngStyle?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to bind multiple object property to ngStyle like below;

```
<button [ngStyle]="{top: obj.pos.Y + 'px', left: obj.pos.X + 'px'}"...
```

My object var;

```
private obj = {"pos":{"X": 100, "Y":100}}
```

Is there any way to bind these variables to my ngStyle directive?

Comment: Your implementation works. What you need more?

Comment: You should set your `obj` as `public` if you use it in your template.

Comment: Make it public not private, should work